# Cucumber list locations of undefined steps

Tags: cucumber

I noticed some tests have accidentally become undefined, and missed. Unlike errors, their location is not listed.

From reading the help file, I tried:

```
cucumber -dS
```

which does a dry run and thus allows quick recognition of undefined tests. But the strict option is not causing them to throw errors, so I don't get their location listed.

I googled for the cucumber man page, but only I found ["Cucumber Man (2004)"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1557192/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl) and cukes.info

Answer (score 0):

You should try:

```
bundle exec cucumber features/product/product.feature -r features/
```

A you can see the first option of cucumber help with

```
 bundle exec cucumber --help

-r, --require LIBRARY|DIR        Require files before executing the features. If this
                                 option is not specified, all *.rb files that are
                                 siblings or below the features will be loaded auto-
                                 matically. Automatic loading is disabled when this
                                 option is specified, and all loading becomes explicit.
                                 Files under directories named "support" are always
                                 loaded first.
                                 This option can be specified multiple times.
```